# Split datalist into sections

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, datalist

Within my datalist, I want to create a separation dividing each `ItemTemplate` with a new year, when a different year occurs.

I select my data using:

```
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM code_post", dbcon);
```

And within this field, a `date` denotes the year it was created. For instance 2011, 2010, 2009.

How can I make a heading of a new year division when a different year occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was by making one trip to the database, and having the code such as

```
private String previousYear;
public string outputHeader(object y){
  String year = y.ToString();
   if(!previousYear.equals(year)){
      previousYear = year;
      return year;
   }
   return "";
}
```

and inside the item template i did

```
<%# outputHeader(Eval("date")) %>
```

This allows for one trip to the DB, and is far more efficent/flexible than the previously suggest methods

Answer (score 0):

As of now the data is in a flat hierarchy i.e something like `List<DataObject>`. You can use Linq or for-loops to make it in `Dictionary<int,List<DataObject>>` where each entry in the dictionary key will be year value and the Value will be List of Dataobject for that year. Than your repeater should have a repeater inside it and then bind this Dictionary object to the outer repeater and the inner repeater data source should be DataItem.Value (i.e the Value part of the current KeyValue pair which is bound to outer repeater data item).

This is not a answer will you can directly copy/paste but I hope you got the idea

Answer (score 0):

I too had an encounter with such a situation.

What i did was...

I took a repeater and fetched the `DISTINCT` Years from the database.
Take a `HiddenField` and save the year inside like this along with the `DataList` inside your `<ItemTemplate>`.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfYear" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("year")%>' />
```

Then using the Repeater's `ItemDataBound`, i first searched for the `DataList` and `HiddenField` and binded that `DataList` with another method by passing the year from the `HiddenField`.

OnitemDataBound use

```
if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfYear");
    DataList dl = (DataList)e.Item.FindControl("yourDataListID");
    yourDataListBindMethod(hf.Value);
}
```

The only drawback in this is that there are multiple round trips to the database(number of distinct years=number of trips to database).